# Ansible - Dynamic directory structure creation

Tags: ansible, devops

I am trying to create a directory structure from Ansible playbook. Can someone suggest a method to solve this?

My playbook looks like this

```
---
 - name: Install DB2 on RHEL
   hosts: dbserver
   include_vars: main.yml
   tasks: 
          - name: Make additinal  directory structure
            file:
                    state: directory
                    group: db2iadm1
                    owner: db2inst1
                    path: "{{ item.path }}"
            with_items:
                    - { path: "/data1/DB2/tablespaces/{{ dbname }}" }
                    - { path: "/data2/DB2/tablespaces/{{ dbname }}"  }
```

**This is my var file**

```
dbname: [db1, db2]
```

I am expecting directory structure to be created in the below format

```
/data1/DB2/tablespaces/db1
/data1/DB2/tablespaces/db2
/data2/DB2/tablespaces/db1
/data2/DB2/tablespaces/db2
```

But the above playbook is not working

Comment: What is not working? Please provide full commands run, error output, Ansible version.

Answer (score 1):

[with_nested](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/nested.html#nested-composes-a-list-with-nested-elements-of-other-lists) does the job. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: mkdir {{ item.0 }}/{{ item.1 }}
      with_nested:
        - - /data1/DB2/tablespaces
          - /data2/DB2/tablespaces
        - - db1
          - db2
```

gives

```yaml
    "msg": "mkdir /data1/DB2/tablespaces/db1"
    "msg": "mkdir /data1/DB2/tablespaces/db2"
    "msg": "mkdir /data2/DB2/tablespaces/db1"
    "msg": "mkdir /data2/DB2/tablespaces/db2"
```

The same code with data in variables

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: mkdir {{ item.0 }}/{{ item.1 }}
      with_nested:
        - "{{ base_dirs }}"
        - "{{ dbname }}"
      vars:
        base_dirs:
          - /data1/DB2/tablespaces
          - /data2/DB2/tablespaces
        dbname: [db1, db2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something akin to a [`product` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#product-filters) fed into [`join`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#join)

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: mkdir {{ item }}
  with_items: '{{ base_dirs | product(dbname) | map("join", "/") | list }}'
  vars:
    base_dirs:
    - /data1/DB2/tablespaces
    - /data2/DB2/tablespaces
    dbname: [db1, db2]
```